# React Native IOS Xcode release build opens metro server after following documentation

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

So following this .... https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html#building-your-app-for-production

Why does metro still open for release?

Comment: You ran archive and it opened metro?

Comment: Morning Kai - thank you for your response! I am new with React Native especially with XCode - can you go into detail how archiving affects deploy?

Answer (score 8):

Choose your Target go to Build Phases open Start Packager script and replace

```
if [ -z "${RCT_NO_LAUNCH_PACKAGER+xxx}" ] ; then
```

with

```
 if [ -z "${RCT_NO_LAUNCH_PACKAGER+xxx}" ] && [ "$CONFIGURATION" == "Debug" ] ; then
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, some background information: this has been fixed in RN 0.59  https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/23938 however for some reason it still can happen that the iOS release files have not been properly updated while upgrading RN to a newer version

Comment: after upgrading RN from 0.63.2 to 0.63.3 this metrobundle popup on release build in Xcode iOS. Your solution fix the issue but I'm not sure why this happen.